# Unable to use a correct XPATH in Python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm getting the correct XPATH from Google Chrome and verified that by doing a DOM search as shown below:
[image]

However, I'm getting the following error wherever I try to use this XPATH in Python

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a"}`

Any idea what might went wrong?

That's the code part where I'm getting the above error, knowing that the rest of the code works fine:

```
    standard_release_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a")
    standard_release_button.click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because that element is located in an iframe. Although I can't see the full HTML, I can see the `</iframe>` tag that closes the iframe that the element is in.

You need to switch into the iframe first before you can interact with elements that are inside it. There's documentation for that on the `selenium` website: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/

Eg, if there's only one iframe on that page (or it's the first one), you can switch to it first with this code:

```py
iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

and then you can use your existing code to click on the element inside the iframe. (Add element-waiting as needed in case the element doesn't load right away before trying to click on it.)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It is an iframe issue. 

Thanks a lot Michael, that fixed it!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you run that code part, the element might not have loaded yet.
You can use `WebDervierWait` to wait for an element to be loaded.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import execpted_condition as EC

try:
    standard_release_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a"))
)
    standard_release_button.click()
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: ", e)
```

It will wait 10 seconds for the element to be populated in the DOM
If the element is not loaded after 10 seconds, the exception will be caught and print the exception.